# Хук на изменение ветки реестра

Tags: winapi, hook, c#, dll

Всем привет!

Ребята, подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать хук изменений определенной ветки реестра? Я читал, что можно использовать dll injection и winapi функцию `RegNotifyChangeKeyValue`. Но из-за недостатка опыта не могу сообразить, как это сделать :(

Если кто может, помогите, пожалуйста :)

Заранее благодарен!

Answer (score 4):

Посмотрите здесь: [RegistryMonitor - a .NET wrapper class for RegNotifyChangeKeyValue](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4502/RegistryMonitor-a-NET-wrapper-class-for-RegNotifyC). Пример использования:

```
RegistryMonitor m = new RegistryMonitor(RegistryHive.CurrentUser, "...");

m.RegChanged += new EventHandler(OnRegChanged);

m.Start(); 
// ...    
m.Stop();
```